# How to connect to instrument through USB using c#

Tags: c#, initialization, usb, communication

I am trying to use the Ivi.Visa.Interop .dll to communicate to a Voltech PM1000+ power meter using USB. I'm relatively new to C# and do not know really where to start. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community. I have already talked to a different instrument using GPIB and here is the code for that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ivi.Visa.Interop;


namespace commOverIP
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitiateIOBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ///testing out excel
        InitiateIOBtn.Text = "Initializing";



        try
        {
            // resource manager and message-based session manager
            Ivi.Visa.Interop.ResourceManager mngr = new Ivi.Visa.Interop.ResourceManager();

            // GPIB address
            string srcAddress = "GPIB::27::INSTR"; // GPIB address of data acquisition
            //setting up communication
            Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488 instrument = new Ivi.Visa.Interop.FormattedIO488();
            Ivi.Visa.Interop.IMessage Imsg = (mngr.Open(srcAddress, Ivi.Visa.Interop.AccessMode.NO_LOCK, 1000, "") as IMessage);
            instrument.IO = Imsg;

            instrument.IO.Clear();//clear io buffer
            instrument.WriteString("*RST", true);//send RST? command to instrument
            instrument.WriteString("*IDN?", true);//send IDN? command to instrument
            returnOfCommand.Text = instrument.ReadString();//read IDN? result

            //close communication
            instrument.IO.Close();
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(instrument);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mngr);

            InitiateIOBtn.Text = "Initialize I/O";
            //*/
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }
        InitiateIOBtn.Text = "Initialize I/O";
    }
}
}
```

This works fine but USB seems to be a different beast. The only real lead I found was in the .dll with the:
IUsb.Init(string, Ivi.Visa.Interop.AccessMode, int, string)
I tried implementing this but I don't really know where to start.

If anyone could give me an example of how to query a "*IDN?" command that would be great. Or, even if there is a better way of doing this than through the Ivi.Visa.Interop dll.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seeing how this is very specific to a piece of equipment 99.9% of us don't have, you may not get a lot of help here. I would suggest contacting the people who published the API and ask for help directly.

Comment: I'm not looking for a specific set of code. I'm looking for how to open, write, read, and close a USB port. "*IDN?" is just a standard command you send to an instrument to read the identity of the instrument. I'm not looking for exact commands, I'm looking for direction.

Answer (score 2):

Restart your device once. Clearing the IO also helps. Afterwards following code should work fine:

```
    string resourceString= "USB0::xxx::xxx::xxx::0::INSTR";  
    ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager();  
    FormattedIO488 connection = new FormattedIO488();
    connection.IO = (IMessage)manager.Open(resourceString, AccessMode.NO_LOCK, 0, "");
    connection.IO.Clear();
    connection.WriteString("*IDN?", true);
    string result = connection.ReadString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I do what you are asking all of the time and I completely understand how frustrating it can be.  I remember doing Google searches to come up with this code.  The code actually came from some Keysight documentation when I bought the Agilent 82357B USB/GPIB Controller.

This can be adapted for any GPIB instrument, the only difference being the strings that you send to the instrument.  These can be obtained by getting the programming manual for the instrument in which you're interested.

I installed the Keysight (formerly Agilent) I/O Library Suites that is used with the Agilent 82357B.  One thing that is not obvious is that you should disable the 'Auto Discovery' option, as this feature will occasionally put your device in Local mode.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// Add reference for VISA-COM 5.9 Type Library
using Ivi.Visa.Interop;

namespace USBCommunications
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Gpib.Write(address: 5, command: "*IDN?");
            bool success = Gpib.Read(address: 5, valueRead: out string valueRead);
            System.Console.WriteLine($"The ID is {valueRead}");

            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Gpib
    {
        static ResourceManager resourceManager;
        static FormattedIO488 ioObject;

        public static bool Write(byte address, string command)
        {
            resourceManager = new ResourceManager();
            ioObject = new FormattedIO488();

            string addr = $"GPIB::{address.ToString()}::INSTR";

            try
            {
                ioObject.IO = (IMessage)resourceManager.Open(addr, AccessMode.NO_LOCK, 0, "");
                Thread.Sleep(20);
                ioObject.WriteString(data: command, flushAndEND: true);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                try { ioObject.IO.Close(); }
                catch { }
                try { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ioObject); }
                catch { }
                try { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resourceManager); }
                catch { }
            }
        }


        public static bool Read(byte address, out string valueRead)
        {
            resourceManager = new ResourceManager();
            ioObject = new FormattedIO488();

            string addr = $"GPIB::{address.ToString()}::INSTR";

            try
            {
                ioObject.IO = (IMessage)resourceManager.Open(addr, AccessMode.NO_LOCK, 0, "");
                Thread.Sleep(20);
                valueRead = ioObject.ReadString();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                valueRead = "";
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                try { ioObject.IO.Close(); }
                catch { }
                try { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ioObject); }
                catch { }
                try { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resourceManager); }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Happy programming!!

Comment: Also, be sure to see if the specific command you are sending to the specific instrument requires you to wait a specified time to process the command.  This is related to the equipment you are programming and not the programming itself.